# How to add cookie in session in aiohttp

Tags: python, cookies, addition, aiohttp

I want to add cookie in session like in requests library

```
session = requests.session()
session.cookies.set(line["name"], line["value"], domain=line["domain"])
```

I tried using cookiejar but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cookies` parameter in `ClientSession` to send your own cookies to the server. By using `ClientSession` you have access to a `cookie_jar` attribute which lets you pass access cookies to be used across multiple requests.

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def my_async_function():
    cookies = {"cookie1": "value1", "cookie2": "value2"}
    async with ClientSession(cookies=cookies) as session:
        response = await session.get(...)
```

This is the link to the [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/client_advanced.html#custom-cookies) of the latest version of `aiohttp`

Comment: Is there a way to update cookies after `ClientSession` is instantiated?

Comment: Yes, you can create an empty `ClientSession` and then update the cookies using `session.cookie_jar.update_cookies({"cookie4": "value4"})`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to update cookies after `ClientSession` is instantiated:

```py
async with ClientSession() as session:
    session.cookie_jar.update_cookies(cookies, response_url=None)
```

You can see the docs about  `ClientSession.cookie_jar` [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/abc.html#abstract-cookie-jar)